# basic calculus question about derivative of a composite function

Tags: calculus

Let $H: [0, \infty) \to R^n$ be a differentiable on $(0 , \infty) $. Let $x = (x_1,...,x_n)$ and $||x|| = \sqrt{ x_1^2 + ... + x_n^2} $. What is

$$ \frac{ \partial H(||x||) }{\partial x_i } $$

???

Comment: Is partial or total?

Comment: total derivative

Comment: actually, it is partial derivative since $H( ||x|| ) $ goes grom $R^n \to R^n$

Comment: @MathcanbeFun:  why not edit that into your question?

Comment: @Way to go!  Way to go!  Said it twice to get enough characters!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the chain rule on the components $H_i(\Vert x \Vert)$ of $H(\Vert x \Vert)$:

$\dfrac{\partial H_i(r)}{\partial x_j} = \dfrac{dH_i(r)}{dr} \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x_j} = \dfrac{dH_i(r)}{dr} \dfrac{x_j}{r}, \tag{1}$

where

$r = \Vert x \Vert = \sqrt{\sum_1^n x_i^2}. \tag{2}$

Of course, we have to stay away from $x = 0$, where the square-root is badly behaived.  The final answer is then the $j$-th column of the Jacobean matrix $J_H$ of $H(\Vert x \Vert) = H(r)$:

$J_H = [\dfrac{\partial H_i(r)}{\partial x_j}] = [\dfrac{dH_i(r)}{dr}\dfrac{x_j}{r}]. \tag{3}$

Hope this helps!  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***